# Animation in the HTML

Tags: html, animation, activex, dhtml

I am trying to execute the below animation, so that the Line no's will get displayed at a specific interval of time. But this is not working in IE as well chrome. The below code displays a blank window and doesn't display the text "Line1 , etc...". How to play the direct animation using the sequence in IE and Chrome.

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<!-- Fig. 31.4: sequencer.html -->
<!-- Sequencer Control -->

<html xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Sequencer Control</title>


<script type = "text/javascript">

sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 2.0, "show( line1 )",1,0.050,1);
sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 4.0, "show( line2 )",1,0.050,1);
sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 6.0, "show( line3 )",1,0.050,1 );


</script>


<script type = "text/javascript">

 function show( object )
{
     object.style.visibility = "visible"; 
 }

function start()
{
    sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).Play();
}



</script>

</head>
<body style = "background-color: lightblue" window.onload = "start()">
<div id = "line1" style = "position: absolute; left: 80;
top: 30;visibility: hidden ">
Hello Anu </div>

<div id = "line2" style = "position: absolute; left: 110;
top: 60;visibility: hidden ">
Hello Banu </div>

<div id = "line3" style = "position: absolute; right: 160;
top:160;visibility: hidden">Hello Renu</div>

<object id = "sequencer" classid =
"CLSID:B0A6BAE2-AAF0-11d0-A152-00A0C908DB96">
</object>


</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED :** This another example from the reference http://www.it.uom.gr/project/deitel/pdf/pdf20/iw3htp_20.pdf

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
 <HTML>

 <!-- Fig 20.4: sequencer.html -->
 <!-- Sequencer Control -->

 <HEAD>

 <STYLE TYPE = "text/css">

 DIV { font-size: 2em;
 color: white;
 font-weight: bold }

 </STYLE>

 <SCRIPT FOR = "sequencer" EVENT = "oninit">
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 2.0, "show( line1 )" );
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 4.0, "show( line2 )" );
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 6.0, "show( line3 )" );
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 7.0, "show( line4 )" );
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).at( 8.0, "runPath()" );
 </SCRIPT>

 <SCRIPT>
 function show( object )
 {
 object.style.visibility = "visible";
 }

 function start()
 {
 sequencer.Item( "showThem" ).Play();
 }

 function runPath()
 {
 pathControl.Play();
 }
 </SCRIPT>
 </HEAD>

 <BODY STYLE = "background-color: lightblue" ONLOAD = "start()">

 <DIV ID = "line1" STYLE = "position: absolute; left: 50;
 top: 10; visibility: hidden">Sequencer DirectAnimation</DIV>

 <DIV ID = "line2" STYLE = "position: absolute; left: 70;
 top: 60; visibility: hidden">ActiveX Control</DIV>

 <DIV ID = "line3" STYLE = "position: absolute; left: 90;
 top: 110; visibility: hidden">Controls time intervals</DIV>

 <DIV ID = "line4" STYLE = "position: absolute; left: 110;
 top:160; visibility: hidden">For dynamic effects</DIV>

 <OBJECT ID = "sequencer"
 CLASSID = "CLSID:B0A6BAE2-AAF0-11d0-A152-00A0C908DB96">
 </OBJECT>

 <OBJECT ID = "pathControl"
 CLASSID = "CLSID:D7A7D7C3-D47F-11D0-89D3-00A0C90833E6">
 <PARAM NAME = "AutoStart" VALUE = "0">
 <PARAM NAME = "Repeat" VALUE = "1">
 <PARAM NAME = "Relative" VALUE = "1">
 <PARAM NAME = "Duration" VALUE = "2">
 <PARAM NAME = "Shape" VALUE = "PolyLine( 2, 0, 0, 250, 0 )">
 <PARAM NAME = "Target" VALUE = "line4">
 </OBJECT>

 </BODY>
 </HTML>
```

Even the above too doesnt work on any browsers

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use CSS Animations?

Comment: Does this work in any browser?

Comment: The above is not working in any browser.

Comment: I need to use the Direct animation

Comment: This is set up as XHTML, not HTML, and must be served as application/xml+xhtml. I don't think it will work from the desktop or served any other way. That said, I'm not sure the javascript on the `<object>` element is usable.